# Aplicacion iOS detras de un login

Tags: flutter, ios, react-native, nativescript, app-store

Estoy creando una aplicación para ios, donde todas las funciones principales están detrás de un Login.
Las credenciales del login, son entregadas por un administrador.

Estuve hablando con algunos colegas y me dijeron que no voy a poder publicarlo debido a las verificaciones del appstore, ya que requiere que las aplicaciones que se pueden usar sin iniciar sesión.

Mi plan es agregarlo en la tienda (pública, no privada).

¿Hay algún problema con la publicación de una aplicación a la que solo se puede acceder a través de un inicio de sesión?

¡gracias!

Comment: Esta es la comunidad en español, por lo que debes postear en ese idioma.

Comment: ahi lo cambio a español! mil disculpas!

Comment: Simple: Creas una cuenta de usuario a modo de tester y se la asignas a los que verificarán la app cuando la publiques en AppStore. Por otro lado, quizás te haga bien cambiar de colegas :v

Comment: @fredyfx decis que por mas que la app que publico publica sea solo un login y luego tenga dentro todos los features, apple lo aprueba? tendras algun link a esa politica o algo donde pueda leer? gracias!

Comment: ¿Cuántas APPS de redes sociales hacen lo mismo y están en la AppStore? Tenga, a leer: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha sido de utilidad, le das click en el check del costado que solo tú como creador de la pregunta puede ver. Esto ayudará a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos.

Comment: millones de gracias @fredyfx! ahi lo hice! excelente material!!!

Comment: Un placer colaborar :D Ahora vaya y actualice a sus colegas :v

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque la pregunta no es técnica, hay una confusión grande para resolver y bueno, ahí le vamos.

> ¿Hay algún problema con la publicación de una aplicación a la que solo se puede acceder a través de un inicio de sesión?

Ninguno, simplemente sigue las especificaciones. ¿Cuántas APPS de redes sociales hacen lo mismo y están en la AppStore?

Lectura obligatoria:
https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Extracto exacto:

> Provide App Review with full access to your app. If your app includes account-based features, provide either an active demo account or fully-featured demo mode, plus any other hardware or resources that might be needed to review your app (e.g. login credentials or a sample QR code)

Resumido en el buen español:

Genera una cuenta demo para que los que validen la app, puedan revisar todas las características.

Más información: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/guidelines/